# Submitting spring boot application jar to spark-submit

Tags: spring, apache-spark, spring-boot

I am pretty new to spark, and i am trying to try out spark submit. I created an application in spring boot , used `mvn package` to create a jar . But when i am trying to submit the jar to `spark-submit` , it is **not able to find the Main class** . But the main class is present in the jar.

```
 spark-submit --class com.dip.sparkapp.SparkappApplication --master local target/sparkapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: How do you package your spark application? With spring plugin?

Comment: Yes .   I am using spring boot mvn plugin                                                                                                
        <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

Answer (score 16):

We ran into the same problem, actually, on the same day you posted this.  Our solutions was to use the shade plugin for maven to edit our build a bit.  We found that when packaging with the spring-boot-maven plugin it nested our classes in BOOT-INF/classes which spark didn't like.  I'll paste the relevant section so you can try it out on your own application -- good luck!

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>false</keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found that simply skipping the class name from spark-submit works, i.e. --class com.dip.sparkapp.SparkappApplication

Answer (score 2):

If your are using gradle this will work for shadow plugin:

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.*

...

plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '2.0.4'
}

...

shadowJar {
    zip64 true
    mergeServiceFiles()
    append 'META-INF/spring.handlers'
    append 'META-INF/spring.schemas'
    append 'META-INF/spring.tooling'
    transform(PropertiesFileTransformer) {
        paths = ['META-INF/spring.factories' ]
        mergeStrategy = "append"
    }
}
```

Taken from here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1828#issuecomment-607352468

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
    <manifestEntries>
        <Main-Class>packagename.classname</Main-Class>
    </manifestEntries>
</transformer>
```