# ClassNotFound when submit a Spring-boot-fat-jar to spark

Tags: apache-spark

when I build a fat jar using spring-boot, its name is 
**sparker4m-0.0.1.jar**

And I "spark-submit" it to spark cluster.

`./bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode client --class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher ~/Desktop/sparker4m-0.0.1.jar --spark.master=spark://172.16.179.52:7077 --source_path=file:///usr/local/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/hdfs_mock/1530842877616 --out_path=file:///usr/local/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/hdfs_mock/153084287761_out --hadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop`

You can see I use " --class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher", because it's the main-class of Spring-boot-jar, and the actual Main-class is test.sparker4m.Sparker4mApplication

here is my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Sparker4mApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
       ApplicationContext ctx = 
       SpringApplication.run(Sparker4mApplication.class, args);

       SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test")
                    .setMaster(happyDay.getVal("spark.master"))
                    .set("spark.driver.host", Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
       JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

       .........


       JavaPairRDD<String, String> transformed = rdd.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String, PortableDataStream>, String, String>() {
            @Override
            public Tuple2<String, String> call(Tuple2<String, PortableDataStream> tuple2) throws Exception {
                String fname = tuple2._1();
                PortableDataStream content = tuple2._2();
                byte[] bytes = content.toArray();
                String result = YUVSimpleTrans.transform(bytes);
                return new Tuple2<>(fname, result);
            }
        });

        ..........

        .........
    }
}
```

Everything goes well, but, when **Excecutor** runs, exception throws:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.sparker4m.Sparker4mApplication$1
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
```

test.sparker4m.Sparker4mApplication$1 is an inner class used by test.sparker4m.Sparker4mApplication and it should be "new PairFunction<Tuple2<String, PortableDataStream>, String, String>()".

I supposed that, spark's Executor process use a individual URLClassLoader to load classes, but my(sprint-boot-fat-jar's) classes are all in **sparker4m-0.0.1.jar/BOOT-INF/classes**, and my dependency jars are all in **sparker4m-0.0.1.jar/BOOT-INF/lib**, so the URLClassLoader cannot load the class.

Is there any good idea for this?  needs help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, got solution.

The key's are:

- 1.It should use an uber-jar with all classes and resoures and not in "jar lib"
- 2.Must understand how "JarLaucher" works. JarLaucher is offered by "spring-boot-tools", it is used to "createArchive" and URLLoadClass from /BOOT-INF/*(spring-boot 2.x) and start true Main class.

so, if "1" is done, "2" is not needed, because we don't need URLLoadClass from /BOOT-INF/* any more.

The solution is : use **maven-shade-plugin**(with out spring-boot-maven-plugin) to build an uber-jar, and define your **true main class**(not JarLaucher) use org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer in this plugin.

After all things done, I found a question [Submitting spring boot application jar to spark-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189701/submitting-spring-boot-application-jar-to-spark-submit) was already fit this out, but the answer didn't point clearly that you shoud **not** use ${start-class}(JarLaucher) but **true main class**

Comment: What do you mean by True Main Class ? There is only one main class in my app and its annotated as `@SpringBootApplication`, should I not use that ?

Comment: `./bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode client --class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher` - I have not tried this. I always mention my True main class name here like `--class com.blah.blah.Sparker4mApplication`. Which one is correct ?

Comment: --class com.blah.blah.Sparker4mApplication is your right choose

Comment: if you use spring-boot, the jar you build by spring-boot-mavent-plugin define use org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher as main-class.  This question is based on "how to reuse the 'same' project that include both spring-boot and spark"

Comment: any reference for gradle?

Comment: @villager an answer in this link has the gradle version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189701/submitting-spring-boot-application-jar-to-spark-submit